# Cannot install python-ldap with pip2.7 on RHEL 6.5 due to many install errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, redhat, python-ldap

I am installing python-ldap on a RHEL 6.5 Server. I am on Python 2.7.9.

I am using the following command to installl

```
pip2.7 install python-ldap
```

The compilation process fails with lots of errors.

Could someone please guide me?

The session transcript is at http://dpaste.com/2BQFWF8

Comment: The transcript is unavailable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have the headers `lber.h` and `ldap.h` installed.

To find out what package provides  them, run

```
yum provides */lber.h */ldap.h
```

That tells you you need to install `openldap-devel` so run `yum install openldap-devel`

Answer (score 3):

I was missing a package openldap-devel . . . installation of this package resolved the issue. The following command can always be used to find the missing package when facing compiler errors of this sort.

```
yum provides */lber.h
```